# Start Android Emulator in Full Screen Mode

Tags: android, android-emulator, fullscreen, qemu

I'm trying to start the emulator in full screen mode (in Linux).  I've unsuccessfully tried adding the QEMU option:

```
./emulator @avd-name -qemu -full-screen
```

Essentially what I'm doing is launching the emulator in its own X session without a WM or DE, and I need it to be launched fullscreen.  In Gnome, I am able to successfully switch it to fullscreen by sending Alt+Return with `xdotool`, but that doesn't work when I use it in the xinit script (it can't find the window, presumably because I'm not using a WM).  Specifically, what I have tried is:

```
xdotool key --window `xdotool search --name adbport:emulatorname` 'alt+Return'
```

Is there a hidden option somewhere that will enable the emulator to start in fullscreen mode?  Can you think of another way to solve this problem?